# Share text online, with access control, free but faster loading than Google Docs

Tags: gratis

Suppose you need to share text online quickly, e.g. some code with a password in it. But you don't want just anyone with the link to be able to view it, because of the sensitive information inside. You need access control, and not simply a password prompt because if someone else obtains your message sharing the link-plus-password that gives them access just like obtaining a message sharing a link that lets them in would. A couple of solutions are providing a question-and-answer prompt you know most people couldn't figure out, or even easier sharing it with their Google Account's email address and requiring them to be logged in via that.

In this scenario I've typically used Google Docs. But a Google Doc is quite slow to load, and the process of creating a new one takes a fair few seconds on top of that. https://pastebin.com/ is nice and fast and even has syntax highlighting, but you have to pay to get private (as opposed to unlisted) documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a repository on Bitbucket or Github.

If you only want to share a password, consider onetimesecret.com.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain the problem with onetimesecret.com (nifty for other purposes though it looks!):

"You need access control, and not simply a password prompt because if someone else obtains your message sharing the link-plus-password that gives them access just like obtaining a message sharing a link that lets them in would. A couple of solutions are providing a question-and-answer prompt you know most people couldn't figure out, or even easier sharing it with their Google Account's email address and requiring them to be logged in via that."

Comment: Presumably this also applies to Bitbucket/Github, unless you're thinking of another method with those?

Comment: When you create a private repository on Bitbucket or Github, you explicitly designate who can access the repository, and their level of access (read-only, read/write, or administer).  Repository users must have a login to the repository host and a password that they control themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use https://secrets.so - it recently came out and works on a zero-knowledge basis. Only the link holder has the ability to decode while the server only stores a encoded hash.

The website also doesn't use any cookies/tracking which makes me like it slightly more.